# Databind Complex list in android

Tags: android, list, listview, layout

[image: Mockup]
So I want to create this UI below. It is for a College class and I don't have much time left. I have everything working but I can't wrap my head around making the list of events. I have a java class eventList that populates a List with data from a database. Any suggestions? Will I have to just dynamically add 2 buttons (up/down) and enough text views to supply the data? How will I keep it formatted if I do something like that? Should I put it all in a scrollview on the mainPage?

Comment: Is this wire frame showing a list of three events, where each event has an up/down button to the left and (presumably) an id between those buttons?

Comment: @323go Yes but the number is the total number of votes for that event pulled from the database. Each user can vote for an event up or down.

Comment: Oh, those are voting buttons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a `ListView` with a custom adapter. Each row can be be designed as a `RelativeLayout`, so you can put your event name, location and such in there.

The adapter will look something like this: (code sanitized)

```
public class POPublicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Wrap<POUserPublication>> {
    private final Context context;
    ... 
    private OnClickListener faveClick;
    private OnClickListener shortClick;
    ...

    public POPublicationAdapter( Context context, List<WrapPO<POUserPublication>> values, 
            OnClickListener faveClick, OnClickListener shortClick, ... ) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_publication, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.listId = listId;
        this.faveClick = faveClick;
        this.shortClick = shortClick;
            ...
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        WrapPO<POUserPublication> item = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = null;

        if( item.item != null ){
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_publication, parent, false);
            rowView.setTag( item );
            TextView tvLabel = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id....);
            ImageView ivPubFavorite = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id....);

            TextView tvSubLabel = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.publicationSublabel);
            tvLabel.setText( item.item.pub().get( PO.displayName ) );
            if( !item.item.pub().existsDefault() ) {

            }
            if( listId == POLayer.LIST_REQUIRED ) 
                tvSubLabel.setText(String.format("(Due on %1$TD)", item.item.asDate( PO.dueDate )));
            else if( listId == POLayer.LIST_PREVIEW )
                tvSubLabel.setText( String.format( "(Preview until %1$TD)", item.item.pub().asDate( PO.distributionDate ) ) );
            else
                tvSubLabel.setText( item.item.getTouchInfo() );

            if( this.listId == POLayer.LIST_FAVE ){
                setOfflineImage(ivPubFavorite, SG.isOnline, item.item.isFavorite() ? R.drawable.ls_star_remove : R.drawable.ls_star_grey );
            } else {
                setOfflineImage(ivPubFavorite, SG.isOnline, item.item.isFavorite() ? R.drawable.ls_star_gold : R.drawable.ls_star_grey );
            }
            ivPubFavorite.setClickable(true);
            ivPubFavorite.setTag(item);
            ivPubFavorite.setOnClickListener( faveClick );

            ivNot.setClickable( false );
            if( listId == POLayer.LIST_REQUIRED || listId == POLayer.LIST_UNREAD ) {
                ivNot.setTag(item);
                ivNot.setOnClickListener( notClick );
                if( item.item.isRequired() ) {
                    if( item.item.isComplete() ) {
                        setOfflineImage( ivNot, item.item.asString( PO.offlineUTC ).isEmpty(), R.drawable.ls_doc_confirmed );
                    } else {
                        ivNot.setClickable(true);
                        ivNot.setImageResource( R.drawable.ls_doc_pencil );
                    }
                } else {
                    if( item.item.isComplete() ) {
                        ivNot.setImageResource(R.drawable.ls_check_green);
                    } else {
                        ivNot.setClickable(true);
                        setOfflineImage( ivNot, SG.isOnline, R.drawable.ls_check_grey );
                    }
                }   
            } else {
                ivNot.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            }
        } else {
            switch( item.itemType ) {
            case WrapPO.HEADER_EMPTY:
                rowView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.row_header_empty, parent, false);
                break;
            case WrapPO.HEADER_MORE:
                rowView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.row_header_more, parent, false);
                break;
            default:
                rowView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.row_header, parent, false);
            }
            TextView tvLabel = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
            tvLabel.setText( item.itemHeader );
        }
        rowView.setOnLongClickListener( longClick );
        rowView.setOnClickListener( shortClick );
        return rowView;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if( getItem( position ).item != null )
            return getItem(position).item.asInteger( PO.pubId );
        else
            return (long) -1;
    }
}
```

It's probably a bit more complex example of what you need, but it shows how you can use different layouts for a row based on the contents of the row, and it has clickable ImageViews in it, just like you'd need for your voting buttons.

Comment: So you are using inflater. Is this code a feature of Fragment UI?

Comment: THis is probably exactly what I need. I will have to wait until later to attempt it though. Thanks.

Comment: As far as Fragments go, this could be inside a fragment, but the layout inflater is an integral part of Android and has been around since API 1. Note that this code does NOT do convertView or any other sort of (recommended) resource preservation.

Comment: Okay, cool. I am not an android master and just trying to get my footing before I dive in. Would this be available to use on Gingerbread without the ics support library?

Comment: There's no ICS specific functionality in my code above. In fact, it was developed on GB.

Comment: Thanks a million man. I will get you that correct answer as soon as I implement this. Should be within 24 hours. Cheers.

Comment: Accepted answer or not, I'm just looking forward to hear that it works. Always glad to help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336037/custom-list-adapter

Related but different question