# Custom List Adapter Wont display pictures

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-arrayadapter, custom-lists

Edit: I removed my exception information. With the Help of @Sam I was able to use fix project properties and the application no longer force closes on me. Though, rearranging the layout from image textview to textview image causes it to not display images. Does anyone have any idea why? All code can be found here http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

> I am attempting to follow this tutorial
>   http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429 I have
>   everything working as posted. I am adopting this for a more complex
>   layout. I tried to change something very simple. I moved the image
>   from the left to the right.

BEFORE

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

AFTER

```
       <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

     <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

Comment: Rearranging the XML like that shouldn't crash your app, something else happened. Post your `getView()` method and cut&paste your LogCat errors into the question. (Your screenshot is incomplete...)

Comment: My sentiments exactly. It should be finding everything by ID so why would it fail? I have updated with the requested info.

Comment: @Sam how did you add the scroll? Just format as code?

Comment: Yes, highlight the text and press Ctrl+K (much easier to read!) Anyway, is the XML here an _exact_ copy of your XML? I feel like the id attributes got swapped...

Comment: This makes no sense... Try cleaning your project: **Project** -> **Clean...**

Comment: @Sam the app no longer crashes. If I change the xml Layout I have to use Fix Project Properties and it will run. Except the pictures now no longer show up.

Comment: @Sam thanks Fix Project Properties works. If you post an answer saying that I should do that and then change the textview to android:layout_width="wrap_content" and android:layout_weight="5" and on the image add android:layout_weight="1" I will select yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense!

- Try cleaning your project: **Project** -> **Clean...**
- Or use **Fix Properties** from **Android Tools**

Also your ImageView and TextView are sitting on top of each other, you might want to add `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_weight="5"` to the TextView and `android:layout_weight="1"` to the ImageView.  ... :)

Comment: It has more to do with Fix Properties then Project-> Clean but that was the key to get me to try the other thing. It all Boils down to eclipse being a horribly shitty IDE and google/android not caring enough about their developers to provide an IDE with it's weight in shit let alone gold.

Comment: the thing continues to do this for any edit to either activity_main or layout row. It's super weird. I thought it would at lease be a one time thing but seems to be a bug.

Comment: That is weird and not normal behavior. However issues like this are not my specialty. I can only say "that shouldn't happen"... Try posting new question detailing how you create this error, but tag the new question with [eclipse].

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, although with different components.

What worked for me, not sure why is rearranging the xml file. placing the `ImageView` before the `TextView`
Meaning,

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks but that's how the original tutorial is setup. I can fix it by ordering the layout elements like this but that does not help me, Sorry. I need to know how to rearrange so that I can build a custom UI. I believe it has something to do with the row item. I am not actually looking inside the listView layout but a runtime object row that has items that are incorrectly labeled. I am going to try to do a stack trace to see what function is calling getView to try to see if i can see why the items are mislabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should not do

```
row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
```

but

```
row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null, false);
```

That may be be cause. I already got exceptions due that.

Comment: Weird, I am not getting an exception for that and the change didn't act any differently. Do you know why it should be like that? I am using API 8, you?

Comment: I don't remember what was the exception, and don't know why it happened either, but sometimes coding is really weird. It was on the API 7.

Comment: sometimes coding is really weird...the most true statement I have ever heard